# Yoast Seo change parameter page in a Title and Description

Tags: wordpress, yoast

with yoast seo i have this setting
Title and meta data –> title template: %%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%

in online site, my result title is:
My title of post – Page 2 of 230 – Site Name

it is possibile change a parameter %%page%% in:
My title of post – Page 2 – Site Name

i will remove of 230 from my title. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a translation filter.

Create this directory and file:
`wp-content/mu-plugins/yoast-tweaks.php`

```
<?php // Requires PHP 5.4+.
add_filter( 'gettext', function ( $translation, $original, $text_domain ) {
    if ( 'wordpress-seo' === $text_domain ) {
        if ( 'Page %1$d of %2$d' === $original ) {
            $translation = 'Page %1$d';
        }
    }
    return $translation;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Yes, create the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory if it does not exist. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

Comment: Or put this (minus the opening `<?php` tag) into the `functions.php` file for your theme. Either way will work.